# How to edit a layer in GeoServer, when we change table schema in a database (SQL Server)?

Tags: geoserver, sql-server

So, is there a way to change/edit SQL Server layer definition in GeoServer, when a table schema has been changed in a database? Or you have to delete that layer and then build a new one?

Answer (score 1):

On The Geoserver Layer Page, there is the option at the bottom of the page

```
Reload feature type ...
```

Bear in mind if you change any of your existing columns, any SLD may need to be changed.

If it is just adding additional columns, should be no need to recreate the layer

EDIT:

To handle different schema's, use the PostGres Schema Search Path

```
SET search_path TO old_schema, new_schema, public;
```

Create new tables in `new_schema` then just switch the search order around:

```
SET search_path TO new_schema, old_schema, public;
```

Most likely, you will need to reload the feature types in Geoserver as described above to pick up any new columns.

If you want to use schema names, then Geoserver will see `schema1.mytable` and `schema2.mytable` as completely different tables

Comment: That is OK for column names and table attribute edits, but if we assign to table a new schema and we try "reload feature types..." we get error "Failed to load attribute list, internal error is: Schema 'http://www.webgis.com:8080/:PUB_SPRINGS' does not exist." Obviously a schema name is missing.

Comment: edited answer to include swapping schemas

Comment: Hmm, i am aware for search_path in Postgresql but I am using SQL Server here.

Comment: Why not just use a Default Schema for the db user, then change the default schema when you want to roll out the new table. Possibly the same net effect